# Fibonacci Sequence Squared

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

I have been learning about the Fibonacci Numbers and I have been given the task to research on it. I have been assigned to decribe the relationship between the photo (attached below). I know that the relationship is that the "sum of the squares of the first n terms is the nth term multiplied by the (nth+1) term", but I don't think that is worded right? Would this be correct?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/33goO.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove that
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} F_k^2 = F_n F_{n+1}. $$
That is trivial by induction. Equality holds for $n=1$ and:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} F_k^2 = F_{n+1}^2 +\sum_{k=1}^{n}F_k^2 = F_{n+1}^2 + F_n F_{n+1} = F_{n+1}(F_n+F_{n+1}) = F_{n+1}F_{n+2}.$$

Comment: Yes, but I was wondering how I would explain the relationship (in words)